# compute engine loading screen after enabling billing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

This feels like an odd question to be asking here. I get a loading circle when I enable billing on Google Cloud Platform > Compute Engine > VM Instances.
I cannot access my VM Instances. I do not know why. I would like to know some command I can use in my cloud shell.
So far the only way I've fixed this before is sending a break/fix ticket but, I don't currently have the support level and I'd like to be able to solve this myself.

This has happened to me multiple times.

What command(s) can I use in the Google Cloud SDK Console to fix this?

Comment: Problems with enabling billing is a free support item. Open a billing support ticket. First double check your billing account assigned to the project. Make sure there is credit available on the card, address match, etc. https://cloud.google.com/support/billing AND https://console.cloud.google.com/billing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Bronze support level users of Google Cloud:**

I was able to solve my own problem with the *gcloud console*.

What I did was `gcloud init`.
From there I was able to choose the project that had the frozen web-page with the instance that was running.

Then I was able to run `gcloud compute instances list`
This showed the instance that was running and I wanted to stop. 
This command also unfroze the spinning circle on the *Google Cloud VM Instances* web page so I could stop the instance from the web.

I probably could have stopped the instance from the terminal as well but, running `gcloud compute instances stop` wasn't stopping the instance.